# detect returning to viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I have a project with many viewcontrollers and have not got a navigation controller. I have back buttons to exit my current controller which perform a dismiss. All this works well. But I want to have a button to go Home which need to dismiss several viewcontrollers to reach top level. I can't see how to detect when I return to the previous controller so that I can perform a dismiss.

`viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` are not performed on the return

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your "Home" button's `IBAction` method  use:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This will dismiss all the active `UIViewController`s until you reach the root controller.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken you do get to viewDidAppear, but the above answer is a better solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use notification center

Add an observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidSomethingHappen(_:)), name: .didSomethingHappen, object: nil)
```

Catch notifications

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didSomethingHappen, object: nil)
```

When the `didSomethingHappen` notification is posted your listeners will catch and the selector method will do its job.

Don't forget to remove observers when they are not needed anymore

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:didSomethingHappen, object:nil)
```